# Split Lines seperated by spaces to arrays

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have a text file that contains output from a program. It reads like this:

```
1 2
23 24
54 21
87 12
```

I need the output to be

```
arr[1]=2
arr[23]=24
arr[54]=21
arr[87]=12
```

and so on.

Each line is seperated by a space. How can I parse the lines to the array format as described above, using TCL? (I am doing this for NS2 by the way)

Comment: When you say "using TCL," you mean "using TCL syntax," correct? Otherwise I'm confused why you added the bash and awk tags.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk '{ print "arr[" $1 "]=" $2 }' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned that each line is separated by space, but gave the content separated by new line. I assume, you have each line separated by new line and in each line, the array index and it's value are separated by space.

**If your text file contains only those texts given as below**

```
1 2
23 24
54 21
87 12
```

then, you first read the whole file into a string.

```
set fp [open "input.txt" r]
set content [ read $fp ]
close $fp
```

Now, with `array set` we can easily convert them into an array.

```
# If your Tcl version less than 8.5, use the below line of code
eval array set legacy {$content}
foreach index [array names legacy] {
    puts "array($index) = $legacy($index)"
}

# If you have Tcl 8.5 and more, use the below line of code
array set latest [list {*}$content]
  foreach index [array names latest] {
    puts "array($index) = $latest($index)"
}
```

Suppose if your file has some other contents along with these input contents, then you can get them alone using `regexp` and you can add elements to the array one by one with the classical approach.

Comment: `list {*}$content` gives you the original `$content`. Just `array set latest $content` will suffice.

Comment: @PeterLewerin :  Thanks Peter!. I thought to avoid any possible issues by providing it in a list format, that is why I have added `list`

Comment: You still get exactly the same thing in exactly the same format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in BASH:

```
declare -A arr

while read -r k v ; do
   arr[$k]=$v
done < file
```

**Testing:**

```
declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([23]="24" [54]="21" [87]="12" [1]="2" )'
```